# Issue with finding what a user has inputted with what is aleady stored in my array

Tags: php, html, arrays, regex, validation

I am having an issue with finding the specific input that a user has made into the front end of the website from an array that already contains information.

As the current system stands it will extract the items from the array as I want them if they are entered one at a time, however when I combine the inputs it detects the inputs twice instead of separating the inputs into two different arrays.

I think this is because I am using `strpos`, and I cannot find an alternative solution to this that works. As i just want to get the inputs and store them in the correct arrays instead of both being echo'd in both arrays.

Current System When Entering One Tag (Open & Close):

Open Tag : https://gyazo.com/6e459f6a1dfa517de7c2c18afc68e47d
Closing Tag : https://gyazo.com/48536708a89dd27601e5539ebde3fb51

Current System When Entering Two Tags:

Inputting Two Tags: https://gyazo.com/4eb62fe51383f2cff70746e57c5d26c9

Code:

```
<?php
//Depricated
//$TagArray = $UserInput.split("");
if(isset($_POST['code'])){
    $UserInput = htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']);
    $InputtedTags = array();
    $InputtedOpenTags = array();
    $InputtedClosingTags = array();

    //Array Containing all of the VALID HTML TAGS.
    $AllowedTags = array("&lt;html&gt;","&lt;head&gt","&lt;body&gt","&lt;div&gt","&lt;p&gt","&lt;b&gt","&lt;base&gt","&lt;link&gt","&lt;meta&gt","&lt;style&gt","&lt;title&gt","&lt;address&gt","&lt;article&gt","&lt;aside&gt","&lt;footer&gt","&lt;h1&gt","&lt;h2&gt","&lt;h3&gt","&lt;h4&gt","&lt;h5&gt","&lt;h6&gt","&lt;header&gt","&lt;hgroup&gt","&lt;nav&gt","&lt;selection&gt","&lt;dd&gt","&lt;d1&gt","&lt;dt&gt","&lt;figcaption&gt","&lt;figure&gt","&lt;hr&gt","&lt;li&gt","&lt;main&gt","&lt;ol&gt","&lt;pre&gt","&lt;ul&gt","&lt;a&gt","&lt;abbr&gt","&lt;b&gt","&lt;bdi&gt","&lt;bdo&gt","&lt;br&gt","&lt;cite&gt","&lt;code&gt","&lt;data&gt","&lt;dfn&gt","&lt;em&gt","&lt;i&gt","&lt;kbd&gt","&lt;mark&gt","&lt;q&gt","&lt;rp&gt","&lt;rt&gt","&lt;rtc&gt","&lt;ruby&gt","&lt;s&gt","&lt;samp&gt","&lt;small&gt","&lt;span&gt","&lt;strong&gt","&lt;sub&gt","&lt;sup&gt","&lt;time&gt","&lt;u&gt","&lt;var&gt","&lt;wbr&gt","&lt;area&gt","&lt;audio&gt","&lt;img&gt","&lt;map&gt","&lt;track&gt","&lt;video&gt","&lt;embed&gt","&lt;object&gt","&lt;param&gt","&lt;source&gt","&lt;canvas&gt","&lt;noscript&gt","&lt;script&gt","&lt;del&gt","&lt;ins&gt","&lt;caption&gt","&lt;col&gt","&lt;colgroup&gt","&lt;table&gt","&lt;tbody&gt","&lt;td&gt","&lt;tfoot&gt","&lt;th&gt","&lt;thead&gt","&lt;tr&gt","&lt;button&gt","&lt;datalist&gt","&lt;fieldset&gt","&lt;form&gt","&lt;input&gt","&lt;label&gt","&lt;legend&gt","&lt;meter&gt","&lt;optgroup&gt","&lt;option&gt","&lt;output&gt","&lt;progress&gt","&lt;select&gt","&lt;textarea&gt","&lt;details&gt","&lt;dialog&gt","&lt;menu&gt","&lt;menuitem&gt","&lt;summary&gt","&lt;shadow&gt","&lt;slot&gt","&lt;template&gt","&lt;acronym&gt","&lt;applet&gt","&lt;basefont&gt","&lt;big&gt","&lt;blink&gt","&lt;center&gt","&lt;command&gt","&lt;content&gt","&lt;dir&gt","&lt;element&gt","&lt;font&gt","&lt;frame&gt","&lt;frameset&gt","&lt;isindex&gt","&lt;keygen&gt","&lt;listing&gt","&lt;marquee&gt","&lt;multicol&gt","&lt;nextid&gt","&lt;noembed&gt","&lt;plaintext&gt","&lt;shadow&gt","&lt;spacer&gt","&lt;strike&gt","&lt;tt&gt","&lt;xmp&gt","&lt;/html&gt","&lt;/head&gt","&lt;/body&gt","&lt;/div&gt","&lt;/p&gt","&lt;/b&gt","&lt;/base&gt","&lt;/link&gt","&lt;/meta&gt","&lt;/style&gt","&lt;/title&gt","&lt;/address&gt","&lt;/article&gt","&lt;/aside&gt","&lt;/footer&gt","&lt;/h1&gt","&lt;/h2&gt","&lt;/h3&gt","&lt;/h4&gt","&lt;/h5&gt","&lt;/h6&gt","&lt;/header&gt","&lt;/hgroup&gt","&lt;/nav&gt","&lt;/selection&gt","&lt;/dd&gt","&lt;/d1&gt","&lt;/dt&gt","&lt;/figcaption&gt","&lt;/figure&gt","&lt;/hr&gt","&lt;/li&gt","&lt;/main&gt","&lt;/ol&gt","&lt;/pre&gt","&lt;/ul&gt","&lt;/a&gt","&lt;/abbr&gt","&lt;/b&gt","&lt;/bdi&gt","&lt;/bdo&gt","&lt;/br&gt","&lt;/cite&gt","&lt;/code&gt","&lt;/data&gt","&lt;/dfn&gt","&lt;/em&gt","&lt;/i&gt","&lt;/kbd&gt","&lt;/mark&gt","&lt;/q&gt","&lt;/rp&gt","&lt;/rt&gt","&lt;/rtc&gt","&lt;/ruby&gt","&lt;/s&gt","&lt;/samp&gt","&lt;/small&gt","&lt;/span&gt","&lt;/strong&gt","&lt;/sub&gt","&lt;/sup&gt","&lt;/time&gt","&lt;/u&gt","&lt;/var&gt","&lt;/wbr&gt","&lt;/area&gt","&lt;/audio&gt","&lt;/img&gt","&lt;/map&gt","&lt;/track&gt","&lt;/video&gt","&lt;/embed&gt","&lt;/object&gt","&lt;/param&gt","&lt;/source&gt","&lt;/canvas&gt","&lt;/noscript&gt","&lt;/script&gt","&lt;/del&gt","&lt;/ins&gt","&lt;/caption&gt","&lt;/col&gt","&lt;/colgroup&gt","&lt;/table&gt","&lt;/tbody&gt","&lt;/td&gt","&lt;/tfoot&gt","&lt;/th&gt","&lt;/thead&gt","&lt;/tr&gt","&lt;/button&gt","&lt;/datalist&gt","&lt;/fieldset&gt","&lt;/form&gt","&lt;/input&gt","&lt;/label&gt","&lt;/legend&gt","&lt;/meter&gt","&lt;/optgroup&gt","&lt;/option&gt","&lt;/output&gt","&lt;/progress&gt","&lt;/select&gt","&lt;/textarea&gt","&lt;/details&gt","&lt;/dialog&gt","&lt;/menu&gt","&lt;/menuitem&gt","&lt;/summary&gt","&lt;/shadow&gt","&lt;/slot&gt","&lt;/template&gt","&lt;/acronym&gt","&lt;/applet&gt","&lt;/basefont&gt","&lt;/big&gt","&lt;/blink&gt","&lt;/center&gt","&lt;/command&gt","&lt;/content&gt","&lt;/dir&gt","&lt;/element&gt","&lt;/font&gt","&lt;/frame&gt","&lt;/frameset&gt","&lt;/isindex&gt","&lt;/keygen&gt","&lt;/listing&gt","&lt;/marquee&gt","&lt;/multicol&gt","&lt;/nextid&gt","&lt;/noembed&gt","&lt;/plaintext&gt","&lt;/shadow&gt","&lt;/spacer&gt","&lt;/strike&gt","&lt;/tt&gt","&lt;/xmp&gt");
    //$Tags = implode(",",$AllowedTags);
    //$OpenTags = implode(",",$AllowedTags);

    //Search Allowed Tags Array For Values Containing a Backslash(/)
    $AllowedClosingTags = array_filter($AllowedTags, function($val) {
        return (bool)preg_match('/\//', $val);
    });

    //print_r($AllowedClosingTags);

    //Search Allowed Tags Array For Values Not Containing a Backslack(/)   
    $AllowedOpeningTags = array_filter($AllowedTags, function($val) {
        return (bool)!preg_match('/\//', $val);
    });

    // print_r($AllowedOpeningTags);

    //Check What The User Has Inputted Into The System against the AllowedOpeningTags Array 
    //If it is true then display to the user the tag is valid
    //Push The value that the user entered onto the InputtedOpenTags Array
    foreach($AllowedTags as $data){
        if(strpos($UserInput,$data) !==false){
            echo($UserInput. ": Valid Tags Inputted </br>");
            array_push($InputtedTags,$UserInput);
        }
    }
    //print_r($InputtedOpenTags);  

    //Check What The User Has Inputted Into The System against the AllowedOpeningTags Array 
    //If it is true then display to the user the tag is valid
    //Push The value that the user entered onto the InputtedOpenTags Array
    foreach($AllowedOpeningTags as $data){
        if(strpos($UserInput,$data) !==false){
            echo($UserInput. ": Valid Opening Tags </br>");
            array_push($InputtedOpenTags,$UserInput);
        }
    }
    //print_r($InputtedOpenTags);

    //Check What The User Has Inputted Into The System against the AllowedClosingTags Array 
    //If it is true then display to the user the tag is valid
    //Push The value that the user entered onto the InputtedClosingTags Array   
    foreach($AllowedClosingTags as $data){
        if(strpos($UserInput,$data) !==false){
            echo($UserInput. ": Valid Closing Tags </br>");
            array_push($InputtedClosingTags,$UserInput);
        }
    }
    //print_r($InputtedClosingTags);

    $OTags = implode(",",$InputtedOpenTags);
    $CTags = implode(",",$InputtedClosingTags);
    $InputtedTags = array($OTags,$CTags);
    print_r($InputtedTags);
}
```

Comment: So would you like me to input another tag into the system for each test as in open, close and open & close tags inputted.

Comment: No, sorry, I'll delete that comment.  I managed to build my own `$UserInput` string that should match what your code is delivering.  Only offer a new sample string if my string doesn't accurately depict the quality of string you expect to handle.  E.g. if your users' string can have tags with attributes, please offer a realistic sample so I can update the regex pattern

Comment: Currently i am just checking the main tag if it is open or closed as i do not have an arrays for all the existing attributes. However with the user input as this is coming from a form that the user enters data into i would have to take the input from the form.

Comment: It would be nice if i was able to check the attribute of tag such as images or form elements but i currently do not have the data set to have this work within my pre-existing system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with a smaller validation array, less looping/filtering, no strpos, no array_push.  (your `$AllowedTags` elements had inconsistencies: some with `&gt` and some with `&gt;`)  This is leaner and cleaner:

View PHP [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e02cc45f6e1bf58ec2b983fcddf74dcb1e2ff244)

View Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MlLsmP/1)

Here is the code:

```
// don't duplicate tag names as /-prefixed and non-/-prefixed
$AllowedTags = array("html","head","body","div","p","b","base","link","meta","style",
"title","address","article","aside","footer","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","header",
"hgroup","nav","selection","dd","d1","dt","figcaption","figure","hr","li","main","ol",
"pre","ul","a","abbr","b","bdi","bdo","br","cite","code","data","dfn","em","i","kbd",
"mark","q","rp","rt","rtc","ruby","s","samp","small","span","strong","sub","sup","time",
"u","var","wbr","area","audio","img","map","track","video","embed","object","param",
"source","canvas","noscript","script","del","ins","caption","col","colgroup","table",
"tbody","td","tfoot","th","thead","tr","button","datalist","fieldset","form","input",
"label","legend","meter","optgroup","option","output","progress","select","textarea",
"details","dialog","menu","menuitem","summary","shadow","slot","template","acronym",
"applet","basefont","big","blink","center","command","content","dir","element","font",
"frame","frameset","isindex","keygen","listing","marquee","multicol","nextid","noembed",
"plaintext","shadow","spacer","strike","tt","xmp");

$UserInput="&lt;a href=&quot;https:www.this.that.com&quot;&gt;Word&lt;/a&gt;&lt;aaa style=&#39;color:orange;&#39;&gt;Somethingelse&lt;/aaa&gt;&lt;b&gt;Another bit of something&lt;/b you=can't put attributes on an end tag&gt;";
// <a href="https:www.this.that.com">Word</a><aaa style='color:orange;'>Somethingelse</aaa><b>Another bit of something</b you=can't put attributes on an end tag>

if(preg_match_all('/&lt;([^\/][a-z1-6]*)\s?(.*?)&gt;|&lt;\/([^&]*?)&gt;/',$UserInput,$tags)){
    // match opening, opening attributes, and closing tags in three separate groups,
    // but store only the tagname in tag groups and keep the attribute string whole
    $AllTags=array(
        "Opening"=>array_diff($tags[1],array('')),  // remove empties
        "Closing"=>array_diff($tags[3],array(''))  // remove empties
    );
    foreach($AllTags as $label=>$group){  // loop through opening & closing tags
        foreach(array_intersect($group,$AllowedTags) as $tag){ // loop Valids
            echo "<div style='color:green;'>Valid $label Tag: $tag</div>";
        }       
        foreach(array_diff($group,$AllowedTags) as $tag){  // loop Invalids
            echo "<div style='color:red;'>Invalid $label Tag: $tag </div>";
        }  
    }
    $Attributes=array_diff($tags[2],array(''));  // remove empties
    // As it is a separate can of worms, I will leave $Attributes handling to you.
    foreach($Attributes as $attr){ // loop Attributes
        echo "<div style='color:green;'>Attribute: $attr</div>";
    }     
}else{
    echo "<div style='color:blue;'>No tags found in input</div>";
}
```

This will help you to identify all of the valid and invalid opening and closing tags in `$UserInput`.  Modify my solution to your precise needs.  I'm happy to explain further if necessary.

*Note if your program permits tags containing attributes, the regex pattern will need to be expanded to allow (and not capture) attributes.

Comment: Sorry i was unable to see this answer and check the solution as i got taken into hospital last night. I will test this solution as soon as i get home tomorrow and will update you on the status. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: @TomGray I have updated my code to capture one or more attributes in a separate group.  A tag's single or multiple attribute(s) will be captured as a single string.  So that this question doesn't continue expanding, if you need assistance (after having a go yourself) with handling the attributes, please ask a new question.

Comment: The last question i would just like to ask is how would i get the input from the user form as i now have access to my laptop and have tried adpating the code to take the $UserInput from the form that the users enters their code in.

Comment: @TomGray  I am working on the assumption that your form is properly POSTing the data to this code.  In which case, `if(isset($_POST['code'])){
    $UserInput = htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']);` as you have in your question will be suitable.

Comment: Yes my form is should have been included in my code example however for some reason it has not been included in the example. I just have a simple HTML form that is using POST to itself.

Comment: @TomGray No no, you were right to exclude the html form portion of your code.  It was not essential to the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assitance i appreciate it greatly!